# CapsNet Model Evaluation with K-Fold validation - How to get the best model and evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was trying to implement `CapsuleNet` for classifying some of the digits. All the images are RGB images converted to grayscale and resize to **`32 X 32`** and dataset has **10** classification output.

> **X_train_all.shape**: `(2075, 32, 32, 1)`
>   **y_train_all.shape**: `(2075, 10)`

Below are what I tried so far.

### CapsNet Model

First, define the `CapsNet` model. Following is the main architecture of Capsule Network including **PrimaryCaps** and **DigitCaps** and so on.

```
def CapsNet(input_shape, n_class, routings):

    x = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

    # Layer 1
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D()(x)

    # Layer 2
    primarycaps = PrimaryCap()

    # Layer 3
    digitcaps = CapsuleLayer()(primarycaps)

    # Layer 4
    out_caps = Length(name='capsnet')(digitcaps)

    # Decoder network.
    y = layers.Input()
    masked_by_y = Mask()([digitcaps, y])  
    masked = Mask()(digitcaps)  

    # Shared Decoder model in training and prediction
    decoder = models.Sequential(name='decoder')
    decoder.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=16*n_class))
    decoder.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    decoder.add(layers.Dense(np.prod(input_shape), activation='sigmoid'))
    decoder.add(layers.Reshape(target_shape=input_shape, name='out_recon'))

    # Models for training and evaluation (prediction)
    train_model = models.Model([x, y], [out_caps, decoder(masked_by_y)])
    evals_model = models.Model(x, [out_caps, decoder(masked)])

    return train_model, evals_model
```

### Actual Training

This simply returns `train_model` and `eval_model`. Now following is the actual training process I've implemented.

```
def train_caps(model, data, epoch_size_frac=1.0):

    # unpacking the data
    (x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val) = data

    # compile the model
    model.compile (....)

    # --------------Begin Training with data augmentation --------------
    def train_generator (...)


    # Training with data augmentation. 
    history = model.fit_generator (...)

    return model
```

### K-Fold Cross Validation

Now to train the model and fit data on it, I used **K-Fold** cross-validation approach. Let's say it's K-Fold = 5. Like the following code, we save 5 fold model and save the weight.

```
cvscores = []

for train, val in kfold.split(X_train_all, y_train_all):

    print ('Fold: ', Fold)

    # define model
    model, eval_model = CapsNet ( ... )


    X_train = X_train_all[train]
    X_val = X_train_all[val]

    y_train = y_train_all[train]
    y_val = y_train_all[val]


#   train -
    train_caps( ... ) # calling actual training 


#     # Save each fold model
    model_name = 'Fold_'+ str(Fold) + '.h5'
    model.save(model_name)

    # evaluate the model
    scores = model.evaluate(X_val, y_val, verbose = 0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[7], scores[3]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[3] * 100) 

    Fold = Fold + 1
```

### Problem Faced 1

The problem occurred in the evaluation section. `scores = model.evaluate(X_val, y_val, verbose = 0)` and it showed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-12f206477b39> in <module>()
----> 1 scores = model.evaluate(X_val, Y_val, verbose = 0)
      2 print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[218.],
         [1.],
         [0.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
```

Is there any other way I can evaluate the model performance and measure the scores?

### Problem Faced 2

In this approach, how to find the best model? I am thinking, we can load top (suppose) **2 weighted fold** model and get the average score value or something like ensemble method over them. Below is something I've tried so far.

```
def ensemble(models, model_input):

    Models_output = [model(model_input) for model in models]
    Avg = keras.layers.average(Models_output)

    model_Ensemble = Model(inputs = model_input, outputs = Avg, name = 'ens')
    model_Ensemble.compile( ... )

    return modelEnsemble
```

And load the save weighted that we get **K-Fold** cross-validation method.

```
import keras

model_1, eval_model_1 = CapsNet(input_shape=[32, 32, 1],
                n_class=10,
                routings=3)

model_2, eval_model_2 = CapsNet()

models = []

# Load weights 
model_1.load_weights('Fold_1.h5')
model_1.name = 'model_1'
models.append(model_1)

model_2.load_weights('Fold_2.h5')
model_2.name = 'model_2'
models.append(model_2)

model_input = Input(shape=models[0].input_shape[1:])
ensemble_model = ensemble(models, model_input)
```

This throws an error following. I know, I'm missing something here but can't figure out how to manage this.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-8cec3f452a69> in <module>()
      4 model_1, eval_model_1 = CapsNet(input_shape=[32, 32, 1],
      5                 n_class=10,
----> 6                 routings=3)
      7 
      8 model_2, eval_model_2 = CapsNet(input_shape=[32, 32, 1],

<ipython-input-31-d96b4a5e15ad> in CapsNet(input_shape, n_class, routings)
     44 
     45     # Shared Decoder model in training and prediction
---> 46     decoder = models.Sequential(name='decoder')
     47     decoder.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=16*n_class))
     48     decoder.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Sequential'
```

If I make a short summary of my question or the problem I've faced is that - I can't evaluate model performance using `model.evaluate(...,...)` method. And further getting this **Attribution** error.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the following line inputs to train_model are list of two arrays.

```
train_model = models.Model([x, y], [out_caps, decoder(masked_by_y)])
```

But when you call model.evaluate in **K-Fold cross validation section** you are passing single numpy array as input(X_val).

```
scores = model.evaluate(X_val, y_val, verbose = 0)
```

I'm also wondering in this case if you want to use the training model or the validation model. From the way you called the method and your intention to evaluate the model, it can be deduced that you may want to call the eval_model's evaluate method.

```
scores = eval_model.evaluate(X_val, y_val, verbose = 0)
```